# Constructing class or structures in an improper way using std::launder

Tags: c++, stdlaunder

Suppose you have a `struct` with elements which you don't want to (can't) initialize in the initialization phase, but is not default initializable.
I figured out a way of using `std::launder`:
Allocate a space for the structure, and then use the launder to assign a value at the right place. For example,

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/zje6cYcbj)

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <new>

struct T {
    int t;
};

struct S {
    int x;
    T t;
    S() = delete;
    S(int x) : x(x) {}
};

int main() {
    alignas(S) std::byte storage[sizeof(S)];
    S s0(42);
    
    // 0. I believe that the commented line is dangerous, although it compiles well.
    // *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<S*>(storage)) = s0;
    
    S *ps = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<S*>(storage));
    ps->x = 42;
    ps->t = T{};

    { // 1. Is this safe?
        S &s1 = *ps;
        std::cout << s1.x << std::endl;
        s1.t.t = 24;
        assert(s1.x == 42 && s1.t.t == 24);
    }

    { // 2. Is this safe?
        S s2 = *ps;
        std::cout << s2.x << std::endl;
        assert(s2.x == 42 && s2.t.t == 24);
    }

    { // 3. Is this safe?
        S s3 = std::move(*ps);
        std::cout << s3.x << std::endl;
        assert(s3.x == 42 && s3.t.t == 24);
    }
}
```

The problem with this method is that it doesn't really 'construct' a structure, and therefore will not call a destructor.

0. Is assigning a structure to a laundered object dangerous?
1. Is referencing a laundered object safe?
2. Is assigning another structure from a laundered object safe?
3. Is moving a laundered object safe?

Thanks.

Comment: The usual way to construct an object into raw storage is with placement new: `S* ps = new(storage) S(42);` The way you do it, the object is never constructed at all, and an attempt to use it exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: To start the lifetime of contained objects have a look at : [std::bit_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) or [std::start_lifetime_as](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/start_lifetime_as). But also note code like that is pretty fragile (the size of S is dependent on actual compiler, compiler settings etc). When you are looking for binary serialization I think most of the time using an existing library is the way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `std::launder` to have defined behavior there has to actually be an object of the given type at the location pointed to.  That is not the case in this instance, so the behavior of your program is undefined.

Consider if `S::t` was a `std::string` instead of a simple `int`.  It would be completely uninitialized and so assigning to it would likely cause it to copy data into what it thinks is its storage buffer but is actually a random, un-owned location in memory.

Simply put, `std::launder` is the wrong tool for this job.  You want placement-new:

```
int main() {
    alignas(S) std::byte storage[sizeof(S)];

    S *ps = new(storage) S(42);
    ps->t = T{};
}
```